# Removing a touchpad deadzone in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, touchpad

I have a touchpad on my laptop (ThinkPad X250) running Arch Linux. The problem will be described with respect to the following ASCII-art representation of my touchpad:

```
+-+---------+-+
| |         | |
| |         | |
|C|    A    |B|
| |         | |
| |         | |
+-+---------+-+
```

tl;dr: I want initiating a physical motion along the touchpad from region B to similarly initiate a pointer motion.

Pointer movement is initiated by bringing my finger to region A of the touchpad. Region B is insensitive to touch initiation; however, after initiating the touch in region A I may bring my finger to region B and continue moving the pointer (i.e. the touchpad is still sensitive in that area). Furthermore, a portion of region B is sensitive to touch initiation when edge scrolling is active (and edge scrolling works correctly when it is enabled).

Region C is similar to region B with respect to insensitivity, disregarding edge scrolling.

Ideally I want pointer movement to initiate when I initially touch somewhere in regions B and/or C. Having the pointer not respond when I touch within the touchpad is annoying. I want to get rid of these deadzones.

My `xinput` output for the relevant device:

```
Device 'Synaptics TM3075-002':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (277): 0
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (278): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (279):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (280):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (281):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (282):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (283):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (284):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (285):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (286):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (287):    0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (288):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (289):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (290):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (291):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (292): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (293):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (294):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (295):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (296):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (297): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (298): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (299): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (300): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (262): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (263):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (264):    0, 0
    Device Node (265):  "/dev/input/event18"
    Device Product ID (266):    1739, 0
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (301):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (302):   1
```

I am unsure if I should be using `xinput` for this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of libinput's "palm detection":

- [libinput: Palm exclusion zones](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/palm-detection.html)
- [`src/evdev-mt-touchpad.c:tp_init_palmdetect_edge`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/blob/master/src/evdev-mt-touchpad.c#L2890-2924)

To disable this, since xinput does not show a relevant option, you would have to patch libinput itself or submit a feature request for this.